# Word list as a baseline for measuring a classifier's performance?

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis, naive-bayes-classifier, text-classification

I am working on a simple Naive Bayes classifier that categorizes text messages as either "positive" or "negative". I was told that the simplest baseline to measure the classifier's performance would be to compare it against a word list.

However, I have no clue as to how this might be helpful.

How can a word list be a baseline for a classifier?

P.S. I am new to machine learning and data science, so please don't hate on my question.

Answer (score 1):

The baseline is not the word list by itself, the idea is to implement a simple classifier which works as follows:

- It receives as input a list of standard positive words P (e.g. "good", "great", "nice", ...) and a list of standard negative words N (e.g. "bad", "depressing", "annoying",...).
- For every sentence to classify, it counts the number $p$ of words in the sentence which belong to P and the number $n$ of words which belong to N.
- If $p>n$ (resp. $n>p$) then the sentence is predicted as positive (resp. negative). If $n=p$ then the sentence is predicted as neutral.

By evaluating the performance of this baseline classifier and comparing it to your NB classifier, you get a more accurate idea about the performance of your classifier. For example let's assume that NB obtains a F1-score of 83%: by itself this value is poor because there's no way to know if this is good or bad since it depends on the data, the algorithm, etc. Now if you evaluate the baseline and it obtains only 57% for example, then you know that the NB classifier is good (if the baseline happens to perform better than the NB classifier, then there's a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Features of your naive bayes classifier is most likely a bag of words where each feature represents a single word.
The naive bayes classifier also assumes that each feature (or word) contributes independently to the final prediction.
So if your sentence is composed of a single word - you get an idea of how the model reacts to that word.